# joomla 2.5.6: how to fetch all articles by category id

Tags: joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5.6 and using my custom query wants to fetch all articles by category id. I study **Joomla 2.5.6** db model and found **xma7k_content** table is stores **Articles** meta and **xma7k_categories** stores **Category** info & it seems that we can easily fetch records by id, the **alias** in **xma7k_content** table is exactly what the article tile is but the path to view the article is some thing like

`destinations/2012-08-08-05-05-05/thailand/overview-of-trips`

which stored in **xma7k_menu** table.

> 1. If I remove date/time from path while creating article. (But how I
>      could?)
>
> or how I could use JOIN **xma7k_content**, **xma7k_categories** &
>   **xma7k_menu** tables to get required result

Answer (score 1):

Use Acesef Joomla extension and you can define your own SEF URL for the page, download here http://www.joomace.net/joomla-extensions/acesef-joomla-seo-sef-urls.

Check the document for more info.